# JSON storage via API

Tags: json, api

I'm hoping to store a JSON file and access it through javascript in a Qualtrics survey. The information does not need to be password protected and I don't want to include any credentials in the Qualtrics survey.

I've been using links to anonymous gists eg. (https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/591cf9b1dd8fa70d97451cd1569f89be/raw/9984f8f22929d29d6f612189212059bce5157ca4/a_file), but every time I update a gist, that link changes. So, every time I want to change the contents of the gist, I need to copy the new link into the Qualtrics survey Javascript (unfortunately, I can't do this automatically easily in Qualtrics).

I'd like to be able to post the JSON somewhere that I can update programmatically without changing the link. Does anyone have suggests of an API I can use for this purpose? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use github's [api](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist) to get your gist's content by using the gists id.

So for
    https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/591cf9b1dd8fa70d97451cd1569f89be/raw/9984f8f22929d29d6f612189212059bce5157ca4/a_file

the id would be `591cf9b1dd8fa70d97451cd1569f89be` and then you can make get requests to `https://api.github.com/gists/591cf9b1dd8fa70d97451cd1569f89be`. You may need to have public gists though, not anonymous gists to be able to update a gist and use it's `id` to track changes.

Comment: Yeah; that could work. Unfortunately, I can't do this with an anonymous gist so would probably have to create a dummy account that I could put credentials directly into qualtrics for.